# Error uploading application Python Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have been trying to upload python Google app engine folder using windows command prompt. I have the app.yaml as well as a python file in the folder. But when I pass the following command in the Command Prompt:

```
appcfg.py --oauth2 update C:/Path/to/the/folder
```

I get this error.

```
appcfg.py: error: Directory does not contain an Project.yaml configuration file.
```

Where am I wrong and how should I proceed?

This is my app.yaml file:

```
application: myappid
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: sampleapp.app

libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: "latest"
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#About_app_yaml suppose you did read this and have your app.yaml file configured and in your project root, right?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "app.yaml file configured and in your project root" ?

Answer (score 2):

Check your shell syntax. I had this error message also, by not referencing the right project folder. Note the ending slash:

appcfg.py --oauth2 update C:/Path/to/the/folder/